# How to turn off Finder Tabs in OS X Mavericks?

Tags: finder, macos, tabs

Initially I did not have tabs in Finder after installing OS X Mavericks. After pressing <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, now I always have at least one tab in the Finder window.

How do I turn the tabs off?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can hide the tab bar by going to **View** → **Hide Tab Bar**.

[image]